# bootstrap website images not showing on mobile

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Any reason for images not showing on mobile phones when using Bootstrap 3? (in the browser everything looks fine).

This is the temporary url: www.alweso.2ap.pl

None of the images on my website is visible on mobile, here's a piece of example code:

```
<div class="full">
<div id="page-2" class="container">
    <div class="row flower-row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><img src="images/stones.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="flower"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><h1>Blablabla</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. Maecenas at bibendum nunc</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare porttitor diam, a accumsan justo laoreet suscipit. </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a live URL you can supply us with?

Comment: @BillyMoat - I just edited the question and added the url there.

Comment: The images are displaying fine on my Nexus 5 Android phone :/

Comment: @oneday I think they are appearing, but I'm having to scroll a very, *very* long way down.

Comment: Hmm, thnx for the answers. A friend of mine just wrote that she sees the images as well, I'll check on my husband's iPhone when he comes home. I'm checking on my Samsung (don't remember the model, but old) Android without success.

Comment: @oneday I should mention I'm using iPhone as well! But it does seem like Safari is pushing the container down, very far.

Comment: Ok, I'll see it in a couple of hours, I already feel better knowing that they DO show up on most of the phones. If it comes to pushing down the content, I'll try to figure smth out once I see it. Thnx!

Comment: seems to be fine my mobile, how you fixed the issue

Comment: I haven't really done anything about it so far, for now it still doesn't work on my phone. Anyway, like I said, my phone is really old, so I wouldn't really mind if it didn't work as long as it works on the majority of models.